# As an employee of a software company what rights do I have on my creation?

Tags: software-industry, negotiation, employer-relations, contracts

I am an employee of a small software company, and I was wondering: what rights do I have on the software I develop at the job? Should I license them in any way? (I mean, they have a license for the end-client, but what there is no explicit deal between me and my employer on the code).

What if I develop a framework which is common on many of the projects I work for the company and I want to make sure that, if I leave the company, they are not allowed to use the framework for future jobs?

Comment: Read the contract you signed. Also check with a lawyer in your locale, because even if not mentioned in the contract there may be some rights for you/employer that can't be changed.

Comment: It is indeed not mentioned in the contract, and that's why I am saying there is no "explicit deal" between us on the matter.

Comment: This is a legal question that seems off topic here-- you'd need to talk with a lawyer.  I cannot imagine, though, that your employer would not own the rights to code written by an employee during the course of employment-- that would be gross incompetence on the part of the employer.  The employer will almost certainly retain the right to use your code however they would like when you leave.

Comment: I am not strictly speaking about laws; I was wondering about the licensing of code, which I believe might be common knowledge among other developers in this community, that's why I asked here. I never really understood much about licensing and this is why I wanted to find out more.

Comment: I really don't understand what are these tones about: I didn't title the question: “How can I sue my company”, “How to license things I don't own” or anything like that. I wanted to find out what my rights were regarding code that I written: if it is well understood that work I did under company hours is property of the company, I certainly don't want to steal it. I don't see why you assumed bad intentions.

Comment: This is the equivalent of asking what a speed limit is.  Yes technically its a legal question but the knowledge is pretty common and standard.  If the question were how can i get the rights from my employer then it would be a legal question that is out of our realm of expertise... this quesiton should be reopened.

Comment: I got a clause in my work contract that the company owns the copyright on everything I create during working hours. But I work in Germany. In your jurisdiction (wherever in the world that may be) the legal situation regarding copyright might be different. By the way, the copyright on this comment is legally owned by my employer :)

Comment: Not just off topic, but potentially way too localised as well.

Comment: @jwenting - That is why they got rid of too localized... too localized was a problem that will only ever pertain to you... this is definately not too localized.

Comment: In many countries (US not being one of them), the law guarantees you [moral rights](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_rights).

Comment: @Philipp Actually, the copyright on your comment is [owned by StackOverflow](http://stackexchange.com/legal) and licensed under [CC by-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/). :)

Comment: @reirab It isn't. The copyright transfer is invalid because I had no permission to transfer the copyright to StackOverflow in the first place.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general (at least in the US), the work you do as an employee is owned by the company, not you. Your employer can use it in their own systems, sell it to others, put it on the shelf, or do with it as they desire - that's their decision as the owners of the code.

You cannot be the licensee for the code, nor for the framework. In general, you cannot decide to use your own code within your employer's systems without permission, then go back later and try to license it to your employer.

If that isn't what you desire for "your creations", you need to become an independent developer, develop code and frameworks, then try to sell or license it to someone who will want to pay for it. And you cannot do that retroactively.

I've not heard of anywhere in the world where this wouldn't hold true, but if you want a legal  answer specific to the laws in your locale, consult an attorney.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What if I actually developed the framework independently and used it in my works for my employer? Does that automatically give him rights to use it however he wants?

Comment: I am not trying to *hold ransom*, please be careful with your words. I wanted to figure out what my rights were, and what is general practice/assumption. Which you answered: but please don't flame me just because I am a new user, I think that was a totally legitimate question.

Comment: *“You seem to be trying to find a way around”* that's what upsets me: I don't understand this assumption. I think that in a lot of cases people don't know what their rights are (or are not); in this case, I didn't know what my rights were or what was the general belief/assumption: hence, I asked. No other assumption should have been made on your part: that's all I'm saying.

Comment: @NinGenShinRa you're trying to put code you claim to have developed outside office hours into work produced for your employer and then demand payment from them for that. Not only is that dishonest, it's quite likely illegal. And depending on your contract, that code might even belong to your employer as quite a few contracts state (and laws even, maybe) that anything developed WHILE EMPLOYED belongs to the company, whether created during office hours or not.\

Comment: @NinGenShinRa As others have mentioned, if you develop something on company time and/or with company equipement the company owns that code. End of story. However if you develop something in your own time with your own equipment then you own that code, and if it is relevant to your job you may be in a position to sell the code to the company. i've seen this once before. Unfortunately this can bring up various legal troubles, like if you used some of the company's code to test yours etc etc